# French Railroad Metric/Topology

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

This is a problem of a lecture note by A. Gathman.

The metric:

$d(x,y) =0$ for $x=y$;

$d(x,y) =||x||+||y||$ otherwise.

Let $\tau$ be the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

a) Let $x \in \mathbb{R} ^2.$

{$x$} is open wrt $\tau \iff x \not=(0,0)$.

b)Determine a simple basis for the topology $\tau.$

c) Discuss the continuity of the map $(\mathbb{R} ^2,\tau) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R} ^2,\tau)$, $(x_1,x_2)\rightarrow (x_1+1,x_2)$.

a) Let $x=(0,0).$

$B_{\epsilon}(x)\not \subset ${$0$}, where $\epsilon >0$, i.e. {$0$} not open.

Let $x\not =0$;

Choose $0<\epsilon<||x||$ to get

$B_{\epsilon}(x) \subset ${$x$}, i.e. {$x$} is open.

b)A basis:

$\tau=${{$x$}$|x\not =0$}$\cup$ {$B_{\epsilon}(0)$};

Is this correct? $\epsilon >0$, fixed?

c)Let  $(x_1,x_2)\not =(-1,0)$, and $(x_1,x_2)\not =(0,0)$;

Then {$(x_1+1,x_2)$} is open, and

$f^{-1}${$(x_1+1,x_2)$}={$(x_1,x_2)$} is open, hence $f$ continuous.

But what about $(-1,0)$ and $(0,0)$? Is $f$ continuous at these points?

Thank you.

Hope my presentation is not too messy.

Attempt:

At $(-1,0)$;

$f^{-1}B_{\epsilon}(0,0)=B_{\epsilon} (-1,0)$(Euclidean ball). Choose $0<\epsilon<1$, then $B_{\epsilon} (-1,0)$ is a a union of  open singletons {$x$}, $x\not = (0,0)$, and is open in $\tau;$  hence $f$ is continuous at $(-1,0)$.

At $(0,0)$;

$f^{-1}${$(-1,0)$}={$(0,0)$}, where {$(-1,0)$} is open and {$(0,0)$} is not open in $\tau$ (see part a) of this problem). Hence not continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: It's continuous at $(-1,0)$ and not continuous at $(0,0)$. Can you show these?

Comment: Berci. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $x \in \Bbb R^2$ with $x\neq 0$ we have that $\{x\}$ is open and is in any base for $\tau$ while basic neighbourhoods of $0$ are the standard Euclidean ones, $B_r(0)= \{y\mid \|y\| < r\}$ for $r>0$.

Consider what this means for continuity...